# Starting a .service under WSL Ubuntu-20.04 fails with some tags not found even though they are present

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

We have a product that is built with .Net Core so it can be ran/deployed on an appliance  that can be running either Windows or Linux (a custom build of Linux). In Windows, it runs as a Windows Service, and in Linux we used systemd to manage it as a service as well.

In order to facilitate debugging I am trying to make a script that would deploy this product on our local dev machine running WSL, so that we wouldn't need the appliance to test the product. Unfortunately, under WSL, systemd is not available, so I am trying to make it work using init.d.

The .service file I have is the same as when we deploy on the appliance. It is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
ExecStart=dotnet /opt/mypath/mydll.dll
WorkingDirectory=/opt/mypath/
User=root
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=myservice
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have ran the following lines in order to deploy the service in WSL:

```
sudo cp /opt/myservice.service /etc/init.d/
cd /etc/rc3.d
sudo ln -s ../init.d/myservice.service S95myservice.service
sudo service myservice.service start
```

The problem arises on the last line, which starts the service. I get the following errors:

```
/etc/init.d/myservice.service: 1: [Unit]: not found
/etc/init.d/myservice.service: 2: Agent: not found
/etc/init.d/myservice.service: 4: [Service]: not found
/etc/init.d/myservice.service: 12: [Install]: not found
```

However, I did declare these tags in my .service file (except the Agent one, which doesn't seem to be a problem using systemd?). Furthermore, what is strange, is that when I run `service --status-all`, it shows my service as running (with a '+' next to it).

Being in a Windows environment mainly when we develop, I thought it could be the line endings, but I have made sure the file's line endings are Unix style, and not Windows style.

Am I missing something that I need to do extra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a systemd unit file as a sysvinit script, and that won't work.  systemd unit files are declarative, and sysvinit scripts are shell scripts that contain commands to start and stop the server in question.  As a consequence, the shell is being invoked on your unit file, which isn't a valid shell script.

You may wish to install the `initscripts` package and look at some of its contents for examples of what a sysvinit script should look like.  Note that you can use such a script in place of a systemd unit even on systems that use systemd.

If your sysvinit script is limited to Debian and Ubuntu, you may find the `start-stop-daemon` command helpful.